# changing top padding in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's how I set my top padding in my css:

```
body {
    font-size: {{ font_size }}px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 20px 0;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

How do I change the top padding, which is 100px on the example above using the simplest javascript function **without using jQuery**?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
document.body.style.paddingTop = '10px'
```

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery I want javascript

Comment: so is it document.getElementById("body").style.top = "20px";

Comment: Even without jQuery you can use document.body.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript syntax: `object.style.paddingTop="2cm"`

see link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-top.asp

so it should be:

```
<!-- note that this chunk of code should be after the body tag to work -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.style.paddingTop = "100px";
</script>
```