# Getting padding for a div element from a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a value from Javascript into my HTML code for a value in padding. I have a javascript function that defines the variable *i*.

```
function myFunction() {
  var i = 90;
}
```

I want to use that variable for padding in a div element like this.

```
The variable i from Javascript
              ↓
<div padding=" ">text</div>
```

But I don't know how to get that from Javascript into HTML (I'm sort of new to it and coding).

I have tried looking up on how to get Javascript values into HTML, but nothing has helped. Can you help?

Comment: so select the element with javascript and set the style property for padding.

Comment: In other words, go the other way, from JavaScript, set the property on the element, rather than trying to go from HTML to JavaScript. Also, note that HTML elements don't have `padding` attributes like that that control their visible padding styles. You have to set their `style` attributes using something called the CSSOM.  See for example [changing top padding in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9695468/215552)

Comment: is padding related to style or just an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i = "90px";
  document.getElementById("div1").style.padding = i;
}

myFunction();
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Padding is added around me by javascript.</div>
```